# Fine Uploader Params Not Sent

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm trying to use Fine Uploader 5.15.0, set up with multiple file fields & uploader instances (multiple: false is set on each) which all display and select files correctly. They are posting to a custom endpoint that is returning any parameters to me. Uploads are set to happen as soon as the file is selected, and file and QQ parameters are sent okay.

My problem is when I attempt to send additional data to the server along with the upload.

I have tried including my additional parameters in the endpoint of the request option, and as a params node added to the options variously as follows:

```
uploaders[1] = new qq.FineUploader({
    element: document.getElementById("uploader-1"),
    multiple: false,
    request: {
        endpoint: "default.cfm",
        paramsInBody: false,
        params: {
            act: "action/processFile",
            uid: 4747
        }
    }
})
```

Calls without any parameters available in either form or URL scopes.

Removing the params section and attempting to pass them via endpoint:

```
request: { endpoint: "default.cfm?act=action/processFile" }
```

Works fine, but obviously no additional parameters.

```
request: { endpoint: "default.cfm?act=action/processFile&uid=4747" }
```

Calls without any URL parameters.

```
request: { endpoint: "default.cfm?act=action/processFile&amp;uid=4747" }
```

Calls with "act" available, but all others have their ampersand stripped out, so the parameter name becomes "amp;uid"

According to https://blog.fineuploader.com/include-params-in-the-request-body-or-the-query-string-479ac01cbc63 and other questions on here the first one should work. For the others obviously FineUploader is doing some additional processing on endpoint that is wiping out my parameters.

I'm missing something essential, can anyone educate me?

Thanks!